# SQL Statement- Sort by Another Table

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, asp-classic

I am trying to build a SQL statement which pulls records from a table but sorts them by another table.
Main - is my Main Products Table
MainCategory - is the Categorys of products

Each product can be in multiple categories - so in Main I have a field called CategoryIds which containts the ID's of all the categories that product belongs to. (I know now that is the wrong way to do it)

Tables Layout:

[image]

So basically when I click on a Category, e.g. Brands I want to be able to sort the products in each category to display in the order I want - so thats why I have created the table CatSort
I can put the CategoryId in there with the ProductId and DisOrder is the way they are displayed.

So on my page the SQL statement:

```
Select * 
From Main  
Where CategoryIds = '11' OR 
      CategoryIds LIKE '11,%' OR 
      CategoryIds LIKE '%, 11,%' OR 
      CategoryIds LIKE '%, 11'
```

pulls all the products in the Category 'Brand' but how do I extend that SQL statement to sort them by CatSort, bearing in mind that not all the records in that Category will be in CatSort 
(or would it be better if they were? they only get added to CatSort when they actually sort them to order they prefer. But if a new product is added to that Category, it doesn't automatically get added to CatSort.)

Comment: Consider normalizing the relation between the categories and the products table.  Instead of a column with a comma-separated list of category ids, introduce a table `ProductCategory` that stores one combination of `(ProductID, CategoryID)` per row.  Then you can solve this question with a simple join.

Comment: You'll find this a *lot* easier if you normalise your data structures.

Comment: +1 for @Andomar. This is the solution; it really deserves to be the answer - deserves credit beyond a comment upvote :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by normalizing the relation between the categories and the products table as suggested

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem is that when querying Main, since a record in Main can have multiple categories, there could be more than one value for the sort order.

The following query will kind of work:

```
Select * 
From Main
     Left outer join CatSort on CatSort.ProdId = Main.Id
Where CategoryIds = '11' OR 
      CategoryIds LIKE '11,%' OR 
      CategoryIds LIKE '%, 11,%' OR 
      CategoryIds LIKE '%, 11'
```

it will do what it was asked to do, **BUT** if there is more than one sort order, then the Main record will appear in each of those sort order positions.